# Templates and string conversion

Tags: c++, string, iostream

I am creating a generic class that plans to read/write from a file.

Ergo I am unsure of what type will be instantiated.
How can I convert a string into some unknown type during the read stage?

IE

```
template<class T>
void fromString(std::string from, T to) {
    to = from; 
}
```

Anyway to do this without specializing for a numerous amount of classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do so is using something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void fromString(std::string from, T& to) {
    std::istringstream iss(from);
    iss >> to; 
}
```

Most of the available standard specializations to parse the string input formats, would be covered by the already available [`std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, T&);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) specializations.

---

> Anyway to do this without specializing for a numerous amount of classes?

No, you still need to have specializations for various classes like

```
class Foo {
private:
    int x;
    double y;
public:
   std::istream& getFromStream(std::istream& input) {
       input >> x;
       input >> y;
       return input;
   }
};

std:istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Foo& subject) {
    return subject.getFromStream(is);
}
```

Comment: And this would also work for any user-defined type that is used for `T` and has defined its own `operator>>`

Comment: Sure @Remy, sure! (OT you're just like an iceberg appearing at my horizons ;-) ...)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Course control advised my to take a different route

Comment: Solid answer, will leave this open a bit longer but will most likely choose you for best (:

Comment: @Joseph THX, but I'm pretty sure we have a dupe for this. Still searching, so don't wonder ;-) ...